# IntelliJ IdeaVIM autocomplete interferes with jj ESC

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, ideavim

I have my vim configured with

```
inoremap jj <Esc>
```

This has worked fine until recently (last month or so), where suddenly whenever PhpStorm autocompletes something (a variable for example) that contains a `j`, another `j` will added to the end of the variable no matter how fast I am typing.

So a variable of `$adjustment` which I input using tab autocompletion will end up as `$adjustmentj` which I have to keep correcting.

Any idea how I can prevent this annoying bug?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to somewhat reproduce the scenario with

```
inoremap jj <Esc>
```

in ".ideavimrc"

In my case, it happens when I type fast enough. If Itake a pause on first "j", it just blinks and, aftwerwards, there is no extra "j" in autocomplete.

However, the best way to proceed is to submit a bug report on JetBrains YouTrack website for a specific project (Vim Plugin):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/newIssue?project=VIM